# Launch GIT comparison in Visual Studio Code from command line using git difftool

Tags: git, visual-studio

I would like to launch Visual Studio Code to have a comparison between working directory and staged area with GIT.
That is why I set global config accordingly

[image]

When I type git difftool in command line (Powershell) I am asked if I want to launch vscode. I answer yes, then visual studio code is being opened. When it is opened I can see only solution explorer. No comparison is done. How should I make it work, so I could see a comparison in Visual Studio Code after I type

```
  git difftool.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a resolution of my problem.
Git config should be configured this way

[image]